# How do I white list domain in ASG's?

Tags: dns, ip, dns-domain

I need to whitelist `https://hooks.slack.com` in Application Security Group (ASGs). As I have understood ASGs are static and they don't resolve DNS. Then how do I whitelist `https://hooks.slack.com` dynamic IP address in my ASGs?

I'm using Pivotal Cloud Foundry

Comment: Have you asked them?

Comment: not really, I need to define in a files ip ranges ip kind a looking how do I define ip ranges

Comment: Actually, it sounds like you don't want to define "ranges" - their documentation is clear on that - you want to define IPs that can change.

Comment: ASGs are really only for IPs. If you want this functionality from this product, this is a question for their support.